# PyCharm: Refresh virtual environment for a project

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

## The problem

I have a few projects in PyCharm, each with its own virtual environment.

Quite often, I add packages to these virtual environments using the CLI, mainly with `python setup.py develop` from another local package.

The new package appear in `Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter` and the calls to the newly-installed packages runs, but the imports still appear as erroneous, which drives me nuts:

[image]

## What have I tried

- Changing the virtual environment to a different one, than switching back, hoping it would reload. Did not work.
- Restarting PyCharm. Works, but it's fairly slow, so I don't consider it a solution.

**How do I refresh the virtual environment**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PyCharm 2018.3.4, I solved this by verifying that the correct source locations are specified under File/Settings/Project::Project Structure.  All of the valid source directories should be marked as "Sources" and the venv directory should marked as Excluded, at least that's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. One can add a directory by right clicking on it, then "Mark Directory as" -> "Sources Root"

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue mainly with local packages except I used `pip install -e .` and anaconda environment. This worked for me:

1. Use `Ctrl + Shift + A` shortcut
2. Type "*Rescan Available Python Modules and Packages*"

Instead of the first step you can use `Help -> Find Action` and then type "*Rescan ...*".

The only advantage of this solution is you don't have to restart PyCharm which is really annoying. But it does "Rescan", so does not help with speed much.

Comment: No such action is available (at least in 2021 Community Edition).

Comment: It should be still there, even in the community edition. One reason might be that you didn't have your focus on project file and the action is disabled, see this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21659#focus=Comments-27-4138072.0-0 (try to focus on a project file or check "Include disabled actions")

Answer (score 0):

I have no enough reputation to comment on @Nerxis post. To complement his answer, I couldn't find "*Rescan Available Python Modules and Packages*" on `Help > Find Action` but it was on the `Preferences` search bar. You can define the key binding in `Preferences > Keymap > Plugins > Python`, in my case there was no key binding.